# How to include Background Image when Exporting View

Tags: android, export

My app has an Export feature which exports a copy of a ScrollView.
The Scrollview (including a background image) is set programatically, but when I export a copy of it, the background appears black.

I call two functions, takeScreenshot() and then saveBitmap()

How can I include the background image?

```
private  android.graphics.Bitmap takeScreenshot(View scroll) {
    ScrollView iv = findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            iv.getChildAt(0).getWidth(),
            iv.getChildAt(0).getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    iv.getChildAt(0).draw(c);
    return bitmap;
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File newDir = new File(root+"/NPCdata");
    boolean test = newDir.mkdirs();
    if (test){
    String photoname = myNPC.getNpcMap().get("Name");
    assert photoname != null;
    photoname.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    String fotoname = photoname+".jpg";

    File file = new File(newDir, fotoname);

    while (file.exists()){
        fotoname = photoname+"a"+".jpg";
        file = new File(newDir, fotoname);
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Saved in folder: 'NPCdata'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the Background to the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView

```
 scroll = new ScrollView(this);
    scroll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
    scroll.setFillViewport(true);

        contentView = new LinearLayout(this);
    contentView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);// <-- this makes it work
```